# Modx: how to use [[*published]]?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution, modx-getresources

I am using getResources to display a list of resources, as such:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`7` &showUnpublished=`1` &sortby=`{"menuindex":"ASC"}` &limit=`100` &includeTVs=`1`  &processTVs=`1` &tpl=`listtemp` ]]
```

Note that I am using `showUnpublished`.

Now, I want to add a class to resources that are published, so in my getResources template chunk (listtemp) I have:

```
<div class="listitem pub[[*published]]">
```

So I would expect this should produce either:

```
<div class="listitem pub1">
```

or

```
<div class="listitem pub0">
```

but this doesnt happen - `[[*published]]` just returns '1' no matter if the resource is published or not.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getResources populates the template with placeholders (`[[+placeholder]]`) matching the resource fields so use

```
class="listitem pub[[+published]]"
```

in your template chunk.

Comment: it's always showing "1" because [[*published]] assumes the current resource [which is published]